# Mat-radio-group not getting values in ts if it is checked "true" as default

Tags: typescript, angular6

Mat-radio-group not getting values in ts if it is checked "true" as default in angular 6.
Here is my code.

```
<mat-radio-group formControlName="code" *ngIf=" codename.length == 1">
   <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let animal of animals| keyvalue; let i = index" value="{{animal.value.an.anCode}}" [checked]="i === 0"> {{animal.value.an.anName}}
   </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

### Am getting null value in ts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide the data in animals and what you mean by selected as default ?

Comment: @Allabakash it is an array of array in object form. if it is not selected as default , then I am getting the values.

Comment: @RaruChempazhanthy can you provide your question in stackblitz